# Undefined Index:email Error In Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I want to make login functionality for my website. But unfortunately it is giving undefined Index:email in my AdminController:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
        if($request->isMethod('post'))
        {
            $data = $request->input();
            if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $data['email'], 'password' => $data['password'],'admin' => '1'])) {
                echo "Success";
                //console.log("Successfull");
                die;
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Failed";
                //console.log("Failed");
                die;
            }
        }
        return view('admin.admin_login');
 }
```

In Blade:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text bg-success text-white" id="basic-addon1"><i class="ti-user"></i></span>
    </div>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Email" aria-label="Email" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required="">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change  `$data['email']` to `$request->email`.Because $request contain object not an array

You can do the following

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
        if($request->isMethod('post'))
        {

            if (Auth::attempt(['email' =>$request->email, 'password' => $request->password,'admin' => '1'])) {
                echo "Success";
                //console.log("Successfull");
                die;
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Failed";
                //console.log("Failed");
                die;
            }
        }
        return view('admin.admin_login');
 }
```

even i dont see password field in your blade template